# Categorise individual cells in data table

Tags: usability, tables, color, data, categorization

I'm working on a data product, and there is a requirement to categorise individual cells.  This is currently achieved by changing the colour of the text within that cell, for example, black = real data, blue = estimate data (see image below).

[image: Color coded data]

I don't really like the aesthetics of this and also it wouldn't help users that are colour blind, so I have been looking at alternative options.  One way I thought of achieving this is through a coloured dot next to the value, with a tooltip that shows on hover to help colour blind users (shown below).  However the stakeholders didn't really like this option.

Can anyone help me to find a solution that is both accessible, but also aesthetically pleasing?

[image: Coloured dot next to value]

Comment: I'm assuming the real data should appear more prominent than the estimated data?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The data should carry equal importance - also there are more data types other than real/estimate, these were just two examples.

Comment: How many different categories would you expect to see in a given table?

Comment: At the minute there are just 4.  There is the possibility that it could grow to more, but it wouldn't be many extra.

Answer (score 1):

Designing for colorblind users doesn't mean that you are not allowed to use colors. It rather means that the colors e.g. should have a big difference in their brightness:

[image]

Source: https://designshack.net/articles/accessibility/tips-for-designing-for-colorblind-users/

Here is another example: Bad (pale, unsaturated colors) vs. Good (vivid colors) vs. Best (including different textures)

[image]

[image]

Source (with detailed explanations): http://jfly.iam.u-tokyo.ac.jp/color/

I would suggest that you use background-colors instead of font-colors. This way there is more space for the color, making it easier to compare the values (and I think it will look better), and making it easier to apply textures.

Answer (score 0):

**Use color to emphasise the meaning but don't rely only on it**. For the solution try to start without color and then push color to help. This is your image in black and white (and greys):

[image]

You could take different approaches to make some elements stand over the others:

- Font-weight
- Field background (lightness first, then saturation)
- Be explicit by either writing the word "Estimate", "E" or a symbol next to each field with a legend below. Similar to how required inputs have an asterisk in the label and below it says * Required.

This is an example without color:

[image]

As a side note I think it is better to align the text to the center in this case.